# Python Blackjack: Updating number of wins after each game

Tags: python, python-2.7, blackjack

This is the function in my blackjack python program for determining the winner of a round. The counts playerScore and dealerScore are supposed to increment with each win, but when running the game multiple times they never increase past 1. I think I need another loop or function to deal with this, but how can I properly increment the wins with multiple plays?

```
def total(self, dealer):
    # determines winner
    playerScore=0
    dealerScore=0
    if self.hand_sum > dealer.hand_sum:
        print("\nYou won the hand!")
        playerScore+=1
    elif self.hand_sum < dealer.hand_sum:
        if dealer.hand_sum <= 21:
            print("\nYou lost the hand!")
            dealerScore+=1
        else:
            print("\nDealer busted\n")
    else:
        print("\nYou tied\n")

    print("Dealer's hand:", dealer.cards, "   Dealer's sum:",      dealer.hand_sum)
    print("Your hand:", self.cards, "Your sum:", self.hand_sum)
    print("\n*******************\n")
    print("Number of Wins:\n")
    print("Player: %d")%playerScore
    print("Dealer: %d")%dealerScore
    print("\n*******************\n")
    start()
```

Comment: You set those variables to zero every time that function begins. Are you surprised that they keep going back to zero?

Comment: Not anymore! That's a bad miss.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run the total function, you reset the scores to 0.  If you did that at the start of the application instead your counts wouldn't get reset.  Best I can say with only this part of the code available.